# Social Network Site with following, groups and commerce - drupal?

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, social-networking

I want to create a social network style site where I have:

- Organizations (groups)
- Divisions (subgroups)
- Members
- Products
- AND: Users

Organizations, Division, Members, Products are entered by admin or invitation only. Users can register themselves.

- Organisations have divisions, divisions have members, members can
  enter products
- Users can follow organizations, divisions, and members and recieve updates on their activities
- Users can rate members
- Products are listed in a catalog (later: with shopping cart)

To me, this looks very much like a task for drupal 7, organic groups and drupalcommerce. 
Are there other starting points you could recommend, apart from "roll your own"?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [page](http://drupal.org/node/206724) for social networking modules.
And to me, organic groups and drupal commerce are good choices for your demand.